# How can I use the Visual Studio properties window to change control positioning?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I'm working on an MFC project in Visual Studio 2015. When I select an item in a dialog box, I don't see any information about its position or location in the properties window. How can I use the properties window to change the positioning information?

[image]

Comment: There is no option in properties window, but what's wrong with moving the control with the mouse or arrow keys? Or you can edit the *.rc file or reposition in `OnInitDialog`

Comment: I understand that I can use the mouse, arrow keys and edit the .rc file but I'm asking if there is an option or something to use the Properties Window to edit this information.

Comment: There isn't. If you want to change pixel positioning, you have to edit the resource file (.rc) in text format, find the control's identifier and change the positioning definition. This isn't the WinForms editor you're dealing with here (sadly).